# PersonID computation (Azure Face API)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-recognition, face-api

I would like to know how the PersonID string (obtained after a call to the PersonGroup Person – Create method of the Face API) is computed. In particular, I would like to know if any information (such as the fields “name” and “userData” for example) can be recovered from it without calling the specific API function Person Group Person – Get.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, do you have any further concern about it ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would like to know what is the explicit computation that outputs the PersonID string (the output of a hash for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PersonID string is just a [GUID](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/GUID-global-unique-identifier) here . If you create a persion, Azure Face service will provide you with an GUID as the ID of that person. As an identifier , PersonID has none business with person details such as  “name” and “userData” .

If you want to get some info of a persion , I am afraid using [API function Person Group Person – Get](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523f) is the only way .

Answer (score 0):

If you mean getting the information back that you put into the `create()` method parameters, yes you can get that from the `client.person_group_person.create()` results.

The `create()` method of PersonGroupPerson has the following fields as parameters: `person_group_id`, `name`, `user_data`, `custom_headers`, `raw`, and `operation_config`. So you can add values to those when you create a new PersonGroupPerson. Once this method is called, a Person object is returned with these properties: `name`, `user_data`, `person_id`, `persisted_face_ids`. So for example, this is what you could do:

```
# Create a new Person object and add that image to it.
new_person = client.person_group_person.create(person_group_id, name)
img = open(image_name, 'rb')
# Add the new person to your Person object and your person group
face_client.person_group_person.add_face_from_stream(person_group_id, new_person.person_id, img)
print('New Person Created:', new_person.name)
```

In the above example, you get `person_id` and `name` from the results of your `create()` call. So, whatever parameters you add in `create()`, can be retrieved from the result.

However, this is just general Person information, you have not yet added images (faces) of this person to this Person object yet, unless you call `add_face_from_stream()` or `add_face_from_url()`.

If you are wondering how the person ID is created, Microsoft has some of their source code available in Github.

Person Group Person operations: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/cognitiveservices/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/azure/cognitiveservices/vision/face/operations/_person_group_person_operations.py

Person class (line 1213): https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/cognitiveservices/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/azure/cognitiveservices/vision/face/models/_models.py